# Cant change stroke Brush Size via Composition, only via top bar. AECS6

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to do this tutorial:

When I try to change the Brush Size of the Stroke via the left panel (the guy in the video does it at 2:04 - 2:09) it does not cover the text (PIC 1), it only covers the text when I use the "Stroke Width" in the Upper Bar (PIC 2).
Am I missing something?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa8kg.jpg (PIC 1 and 2)
I am using Adobe After Effects CS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because in the video path is added to the Text layer, but you have it on separate shape layer.

Try to move you path to the text layer.

Comment: How do I do that?
When I try to copy and paste it on the text layer, all it does is create another path layer.

Comment: First add stroke effect to the Text layer. Then copy-paste "path" value.

Comment: Ok, just got it.
Thanks for the help!